# How to keep the current page active on refresh in pagination? React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using a pagination on my page that paginates the data from an api. When a user goes to a certain page and refreshes, it takes the user back to the first page. I am thinking
I can use Local Storage to handle this. But How?

```
const [playerData, setPlayerData] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const [currentPlayers, setCurrentPlayers] = useState(null);
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);
  const [playersOffset, setPlayersOffset] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    console.log("dummy");
    axios
      .get(
        // `api`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        //////////////////
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        ///////
      });
  },[page, query]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const endOffset = playersOffset + 8;
    setCurrentPlayers(playerData);
  }, [playerData, playersOffset]);

  const handlePageClick = (event) => {
    const newOffset = (event.selected * 8) % playerData.length;
    console.log("yeeeeƒß", event);
    setPage(event.selected + 1);
  };
  console.log("data: ", playerData);
```

and after mapping

```
<div className="pagination">
                  <ReactPaginate
                    breakLabel="..."
                    nextLabel="next >"
                    onPageChange={handlePageClick}
                    pageRangeDisplayed={2}
                    pageCount={pageCount}
                    previousLabel="< previous"
                    renderOnZeroPageCount={null}
                    breakClassName={"page-item"}
                    breakLinkClassName={"page-link"}
                    containerClassName={"pagination"}
                    pageClassName={"page-item"}
                    pageLinkClassName={"page-link"}
                    previousClassName={"page-item"}
                    previousLinkClassName={"page-link"}
                    nextClassName={"page-item"}
                    nextLinkClassName={"page-link"}
                    activeClassName={"active"}
                  />
                </div>
```

Comment: I think if you want to retain information, you could store it in the url (e.g. `?page=2` or `.../2`) instead of using the Local Storage.

Comment: @NotX I am using this Api

http://192.168.18.8/goc-backend/api/web/index.php/v1/player/?expand=specialitiesInfo,relations,specialitiesInfo.battingStyle,specialitiesInfo.fieldingStyle,specialitiesInfo.bowlingStyle,teams.team,cricketInfo,playersNews.news,playersGallery.image,playersVideos.video,playersComments,sports&page=${page}`

Answer (score 0):

Set local storage value as 1 initially if it is not already existing. If it's already existing, it'll pickup that page number value:

```
const currentPage = localStorage.getItem("PageNumber") ? localStorage.getItem("PageNumber") : 1 ;
localStorage.setItem("PageNumber", currentPage );
```

Set the initial page number like this:

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(currentPage);
```

Then on change of the page number (I think its's the function handlePageClick in your case), update the page number:

```
localStorage.setItem("PageNumber", page);
```

You would also need to remove this local storage variable wherever logically, you are unmounting this view.

```
localStorage.removeItem("PageNumber");
```

Hopefully this should give you the desired result

Comment: Why are you using getItem and setItem? What is "Item" in it?

Comment: That's how you use localstorage. That's just the syntax

Comment: Hay! it's working. When I refresh the page it show me exactly that page and it's data where I was before. But the page counting still go at number 1. What's its solution?

Comment: Where exactly are you writing this line -> "localStorage.removeItem("PageNumber");" ?

Comment: You can write react code but don't know what is localstorage?